# Write output out of grep into a file on Linux?

Tags: linux, grep

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep -i -n "searchstring" >output.txt
```

Here I am trying to write data into a file which is not happening...

Comment: What is the error that you get?  Could it be you do not have permission to create output.txt?

Comment: What happens when you execute the command without the '> output.txt'?

Comment: @Shawn, that's not true: the > redirection is for xargs, not each grep it runs, so all greps write to the same output file.

Comment: @Lars true. What was I thinking... will delete previous comment so it does not cause any confusion.

Answer (score 11):

How about appending results using `>>`?

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep -i -n "searchstring" >> output.txt
```

I haven't got a Linux box with me right now, so I'll try to improvize.

the `xargs grep -i -n "searchstring"` bothers me a bit.

Perhaps you meant `xargs -I {} grep -i "searchstring" {}`, or just `xargs grep -i "searchstring"`?

Since `-n` as grep's argument will give you only number lines, I doubt this is what you needed.

This way, your final code would be

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep -i "searchstring" >> output.txt
```

Comment: @Rajesh: then your first part sounds problematic. You should write your code iteratively, so you can see what's really happening. In this case, you should have tried `find . -name "*.php"` to see if you get any results. What happens if you try `find . -name "*php" -type f`?

Comment: You can use `grep --include=*.php ...` to filter by extension in order to avoid the `find | xargs` ugliness

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -i -n "function" {} \;  >output.txt
```

But you won't know what file it came from. You might want:

```
find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -i -Hn "function" {} \;  >output.txt
```

instead.

Comment: <pre>grep: {}: No such file or directory
grep: ;: No such file or directory
</pre>

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have spaces in the php filenames. If you hand them to `grep` through `xargs` in the way that you do, the names get split into parts and `grep` interprets those parts as filenames which it then cannot find.

There is a solution for that. `find` has a `-print0` option that instructs `find` to separate results by a NUL byte and `xargs` has a `-0` option that instructs `xargs` to expect a NUL byte as separator. Using those you get:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i -n "searchstring" > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using line-buffered

grep --line-buffered

[edit]

I ran your original command on my box and it seems to work fine, so I'm not sure anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me.  What happens if you remove `>output.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching trees of source code, please consider using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com).  To do what you're doing in ack, regardless of there being spaces in filenames, you'd do:

```
ack --php -i searchstring > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following command. It displays the output on a console and also creates the file

grep -r "string to be searched" . 2>&1 | tee /your/path/to/file/filename.txt

Answer (score 0):

Check free disk space by

```
$ df -Th
```

It could be not enough free space on your disk.